# Keeping const data in one place

Tags: c

I'll need to store keywords in my C project. Now I'd have to write

```
const char firstThingKeyword[] = "foofoofoofoo"
const char secondThingKeyword[] = "barbarbarbar"
```

The names are long, so I'd rather reference them

```
keywords.firstThing
```

Is there any way to do this in plain C? (possibly GCC extension)

I thought about using a struct, but I have trouble doing anything with it, having left the C++ comfort zone.

Comment: Use a struct? Since these are constants, perhaps better use a `#define`?

Comment: @Evert I thought about struct, but having programmed only in C++ (not C) it's a little troublesome for me ;)

Comment: Er, isn't `keywords.firstThing` longer than `firstThingKeyword`? And if that's how long they need to be to have a clear meaning, making them any short would make them less clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how to accomplish this using a `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct _keywords {
    const char *first;
    const char *second;
};

const struct _keywords Keywords = {
    .first = "AAA",
    .second = "BBB"
};

int main(void) {

    printf("first: %s\n", Keywords.first);
    printf("second: %s\n", Keywords.second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the `struct` should be `const`, too. All-uppercase names should only be used for macros or enum-constants.